# Difference between sd0/sda, hd0/hda

Tags: linux, partition, grub2, block-device

From what I understand, `hdx` is naming convention for IDE (PATA) drive, `sdx` is for SCSI (SATA) drive.

Sometimes I see sd0 and sda, similary hd0/hda. What are their differences ? When would we use number in naming such as sd0 or hd0 ?

It seems that (hd0, x) is only used by GRUB, is that correct ?

Comment: each operating system uses its own convention; `grub` could be considered to be an operating system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hd0 - is a Linux grub2.gfg/grub.conf designation of hard drive 0, even it is sata

`/dev/sd0s1` - usualy a name of first slice in FreeBSD OS on sata0

`/dev/sda1` - a name of Linux partition on sata0

Comment: /dev/sda isn't necessarily sata0 ( if that designation can even be said to have meaning ).. it's just the first scsi compliant drive ( which sata drives kinda sorta are ) that finished being probed.  It can often be a usb flash stick you had plugged in at boot as they tend to detect faster than hard disks, or the third sata drive on your second sata controller.

Comment: And in which case do we refer to as sd0 and not sda?